# Add in files under config catalog in a SharePoint 2007 solution

Tags: deployment, solution-package

Is it possible to add files under the 12 folder in a wsp solution? I need to add a file under the 12/config folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to add files to the SharePoint root you have to include the files in your WSP and then in the solution manifest add the following elements:

```
<RootFiles>
    <RootFile Location='CONFIG\my_file.xml' />
</RootFiles>
```

/WW